# Static QR Code redirect

Tags: qr-code

I had a sign made with a Static QR Code.

Unfortunately, i forgot about the QR code when i decided to ditch my old domain (globexposure.net) and now this QR code no longer works.

The QR code points to:
http://heavenly.globexposure.net/the-churchyards/st-margaret-de-westwick/

Is there any way i can set up a URL forwarder without re-purchasing this domain?
Please can you explain what my options are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

If you don't own the domain there is nothing you can do except maybe print a new QR code on a sticker that points to a domain you do own and sick it over the top.

Answer (score 0):

no only the owner of a domain may set up redirects. it comes with ownership.

all you can do is make new QR codes and replace the old ones.